# iOS - scrollView and setContentSize

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

## Question

I have a scrollview with a couple things in it. To load information to it, I am using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. When this is tapped, my content is loaded into my `mainScrollView`. This image will help illustrate what I am trying to explain.

[image]

Here is how I set my `setContentSize` after my tap gesture runs:

```
    CGSize s = self.mainScrollView.frame.size;
    s.height = self.bodyTxt.frame.origin.y + self.bodyTxt.frame.size.height;
    [self.mainScrollView setContentSize:s];
```

I'm setting the height of the `mainScrollView` based on the height of the `bodyTxt`, which right now everything is working how it should.

## Problem

If I tap on this gesture again to load the same content into my scrollview,  the `bodyTxt` animate scrolls to the bottom, which makes the user have to scroll back to the top of the scrollview.

If I tap on it a third time, then it is back to normal, the content is back to the top of the scrollview.

Every time you tap, the `mainScrollView` alternates from the top animating to the bottom...

I'm not sure what is causing this problem, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you put content offset to 0 every time you resize, perhaps this help you

[mainScrollView setContentOffset:]

Comment: This solutions doesn't fix the problem.